# Meteorjs: How to know if template is re rendered?

Tags: templates, dom, meteor, rerender

I have this code:

```
Template.temp.rendered = function () {
    console.log('temp rendered');
}
```

Which logs only when the website is initialized.

But i do something like this:

```
more = function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('Videos', Session.get('more_info'));
}
```

When i call more(); it does not log the "temp rendered" even though the template dom gets updated with the new documents.
Also tried something like:

```
Template.temp.rerendered = function () {
    console.log('temp re rendered');
}
```

It does not work;
How do I know if A template is rerendered ?

For the moment i'm doing something like this

```
$('#list').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    console.log('template modified'}
    //this logs like 200 times, every time the template is re rendered
)
```

How can I do it in the meteor way ?

list Template:

```
<template name="list">
    {{#each list}}
        <a id="{{_id}}" href="/{{category}}/{{_id}}" title="{{vTitle}}">
            {{vTitle}}
        </a>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Helpers:

```
Template.list.helpers({
  list : function () {
     return Videos.find({},{sort : {date : -1}});
  }
})
```

Tried(not working):

```
Template.list.rendered = function () {    
  this.autorun(function() {
    Videos.find();
    console.log('template re rendered');
  });
}
```

Prefered Solution(from @richsilv):

```
Template.list.rendered = function () {    
  this.autorun(function() {
    Videos.find().count();
    console.log('template re rendered');
  });
}
```

Also the solution from @Peppe L-G was good if you need to call a function every time the template is rendered and if you dont want to register an autorun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `rendered` callback is [only fired *once*](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_rendered) when the template is originally rendered, not when it changes due to computations on which it depends being invalidated.

The Meteoric way to do things is to add a [`this.autorun`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun) to the rendered callback which is dependent on the same thing that's causing the template to rerender (i.e. a `find` on the `Videos` collection, or whatever).  That way you are:

1. Tying your reactivity to the data source rather than the DOM which, apart from being more sensible from a conceptual perspective, also means you don't run a load of unnecessary calculations every time there is any change to your template, which is very important if it is dependent on multiple data sources (you can have a different `autorun` for each source, where necessary).
2. Still taking advantage of a template's ability to stop `autorun` blocks which are declared under `this` when it's torn down, which obviates the need to stop them manually to avoid having loads of floating, unused autoruns taking up CPU and memory.

Comment: Well my point here is to show images after load. Can not add this ability to the images without being there. That's Why I need this autorun. Btw I tried adding this.autorun like this: 
Template.list.rendered = function () {
console.log('template rendered');
this.autorun;} <- this does not work why? I also tried to add the whole Template.list.rendered inside a Tracker.autorun

Comment: `this.autorun` is just a proxy for `Tracker.autorun` within a template callback so that it automatically gets torn down - you still have to pass the function you want to run as the argument.

Comment: in terms of getting it to fire, you have to make it dependent on the data source.  if that's the `more_info` Session variable, you need to do a `Session.get('more_info')` *inside* the function passed to the autorun, so that Meteor knows to rerun it when the result of that variable changes.  Similar if you'd rather make it dependent on `Videos.find()`.

Comment: If you need more info, have a look at [this](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/).

Comment: Well like this i can call the function when i change the session. The point is how to autorun the function when an item is added to the list !?

Comment: But what is it that's causing something to be added to "the list"???  Is the list the result of `Videos.find()`?  If so, make your autorun dependent on `Videos.find()` rather than `Session.get('more_info')`.  If not, you really need to tell me what is causing things to be added to the list!

Comment: @richsliv look I updated what helpers I have and what I tried.

Comment: Can you add the HTML?  I still don't understand what the `list` template is.  If it's just looping through the result of `list` then there's no reason that shouldn't work. Even better, make a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/QyzJxwg7JnDHs5wZK/Leaderboard)

Comment: Addedd the tempate over helpers. It simply iterates through the array. Everything works perfect except the templ.rendered is not called.

Comment: You need to `fetch` or `count` the items for it to be reactive.  So `Videos.find().fetch()` or `Videos.find().count()` (which requires less CPU, but won't fire on updates to the collection).  I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

From Blaze (Meteor 0.8.0), templates are never re-rendered. Instead, fine grained updates are used. If you need to know when a part of the template changes, try putting that part in yet another template, and use the rendered function of that template. For example, if you have the following template:

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
    {{#if reactiveCondition}}
        <p>The reactive condition is true!</p>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

And you want something to happen when the paragraph is rendered, you need to do something like this:

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
    {{#if reactiveCondition}}
        {{> paragraph}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

```html
<template name="paragraph">
    <p>The reactive condition is true!</p>
</template>
```

```js
Template.paragraph.rendered = function(){
    console.log("The paragraph rendered!")
}
```

The same principle can be applied to cursors. For example, the following template:

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
    {{#each getCursor}}
        <p>A document in the cursor!</p>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Must be written as:

```html
<template name="myTemplate">
    {{#each getCursor}}
        {{> document}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

```html
<template name="document">
    <p>A document in the cursor!</p>
</template>
```

```js
Template.document.rendered = function(){
    console.log("A document is rendered!")
}
```

Comment: I don't have a part that's a list that keeps adding I have an endless scroll. And when another page is added i want the images to show after download. I don't really know how I can do this in my example and I'm not really sure what reactiveConditions are. Also I dont know if you guys are having the same problem but for now at my location the docs.meteor.com is not accessible even from proxy sites.

Comment: @user1898399, the same principle applies to cursors (see my updated answer). And `reactiveCondition` in my example is just an ordinary helper that depends on a reactive data source (such as `Session`).

Comment: Well this leads me to another question. How can I access the each cursor from the {{> document}} template ? And thank you :)

Comment: @user1898399, in the document template you can't access the cursor, but the context will be changed to the document. For example, if the document in the cursor is `{a: 1, b: 2}`, `{{a}}` in the document template will evaluate to `1`, and `{{b}}` in the document template will evaluate to `2`.