# Meteor - Run code after 'Re-render'

Tags: meteor, dependencies, fancyform

How do I run a function after Meteor has 're-rendered'?

I have a template, which when rendered, should run a ([fancyform](https://github.com/Lutrasoft/Fancyform)) function that takes a normal select box, and style it. So I placed the function in a `Template.tempname.rendered = function(){}`. All good.

But I also have an i18n feature (usign [TAP-i18n](https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n)), which changes the language by changing a session variable, and this makes the text on the page change to whatever text we defined.

However, the function in Template.tempname.rendered` does not run again, and the select box language does not get updated. I need to run the fancyform function again so that the select box is also in the correct language.

How do I do this? I've read (and struggling to understand) dependencies...is that relevant? Is that overkill? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27504177/2104665) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `rendered` callback you need to have an active computation which invalidates itself when anything in your `i18n` reactive dictionary changes, so:

```
Template.tempname.rendered = function () {
  this.autorun(function () {
    TAPi18n.getLanguage() // make sure to invalidate if the language changes
    /* run your fancy form function here */
  ));
};
```